# How do I make my own directory in QT QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, importerror, qtquick2

I'm trying to make a directory of a singleton QML File "All.qml" which I can import anywhere else into my project so that I can access its objects (namely the drawer). I made a qmldir file, in the same folder as the "All.qml", and even add the directory to the .qrc file.
The contents of the directory is as follows:

```
Module App.Drawer

singleton All  1.0 All.qml
```

But when I type in

```
import App.Drawer.   1.0
```

It says "module 'App.Drawer' not installed". I can't find any other way to access that drawer, as the project is huge with multiple folders and directories. Can anyone help me?

Also, this project has C++ integrated with it. I tried going and finding some file where maybe the other directories (there are other custom directories, which were made beforehand) have been installed, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that `QEngine` can find the `qmldir` file, and it has some specific requirements on where it will look.

First to make `QEngine` aware of the `qmldir` file you have to add an import path:

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
```

Your path may vary, read on:

The `qmldir` file has to placed in the folder structure dictated by module name. In your case it is `<rootPath>/App/Drawer/qmldir`. The "rootPath" is unknown to me, but let's assume you have the following in your qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/ProjectX/App/Drawer">
        <file>Drawer.qml</file>
        <file>qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then "rootPath" is `qrc:/ProjectX` and the import call becomes:

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/ProjectX");
```

Also, the `module` declaration in `qmldir` should be the same as the folder structure where the `qmldir` file is placed. (And I think it should be lowercase)

```
module App.Drawer

singleton Drawer 1.0 Drawer.qml
```

---

If you want Qt Creator to also find the stuff you can use the `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable and set it to the correct folder using the same logic.

You can also place the files in the `<Qt_installation_folder>/qml/App/Drawer` but this means every project can use it and you have to keep it up-to-date during development, which might be overdone.

---

*Edit*

To see if your files are lined up correctly, you can add this debug code:

```
QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```

Comment: Where do I write that command? The engine.addImportPath() one? In the qmldir file? Or the file I'm trying to import it in?

Comment: After you instantiate the `QEngine`, probably main.cpp, before the call to `qengine.load('qrc:/main.qml')` (or similar)

Comment: It shows that it identifies the root folder ("/ProjectX") as one of the import paths, but it still can't find the module. I hope this helps a bit in finding the problem out. Do I have to save the qmldir with some specific extension?

Comment: Can you execute the piece of debug code I added in main.cpp and post the output if it doesn't already help in finding the problem. Also it may help if you post more about the project setup (.pro file(s), .qrc file(s) ). The `qmldir` filename is just that, without extension

Comment: Okay, so I executed the piece of code you added and this is the output that came in the console.
"QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment." Followed by ALL the images/qml files/files etc referred to in the .qrc file. The list of files ALSO includes my qmldir file in this output, along with the "Drawer.qml" file. But the issue still persists. It still says it can't find the module. Even though it clearly is going through that file.

Comment: @Shravan do you think that the `qmldir` file is in the correct path according to my answer? Maybe you can post the output to pastebin or similar

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the file and added it through Qt Creator as well just to be safe. The same issue, it goes through that file and still says that it can't find the module.

Comment: Please also remove the dot after `import App.Drawer`

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. I couldn't edit my question because I'm a new user. It's just 'import App.Drawer 1.0'

Comment: Hmm, my last resort, change the `addImportPath` to ":" or try to fiddle a bit with it

Comment: Didn't work :/
I found a workaround for the problem, fortunately. Thanks for all the help and quick responses!

Comment: Your welcome, and also welcome to post the solution and mark it as such ;-) for other people